# Invalid JWT response with VBA code for FedEx Ship API - What am I missing?

Tags: json, excel, vba, jwt, fedex

Trying to utilize fedex ship api using vba but I keep getting a response of "The given JWT is invalid. Please modify your request and try again."

Here is my json payload

```json
{
  "labelResponseOptions": "URL_ONLY",
  "requestedShipment": {
    "shipper": {
      "contact": {
        "personName": "Nick",
        "phoneNumber": 3155555555,
        "companyName": "company"
      },
      "address": {
        "streetLines": [
          "34 road dr"
        ],
        "city": "saint charles",
        "stateOrProvinceCode": "MO",
        "postalCode": 63301,
        "countryCode": "US"
      }
    },
    "recipients": [
      {
        "contact": {
          "personName": "Nick",
          "phoneNumber": 3155555555,
          "companyName": "company"
        },
        "address": {
          "streetLines": [
            "4469 Road"
          ],
          "city": "BATON ROUGE",
          "stateOrProvinceCode": "LA",
          "postalCode": 70808,
          "countryCode": "US"
        }
      }
    ],
    "shipDatestamp": "2023-06-02",
    "serviceType": "STANDARD_OVERNIGHT",
    "packagingType": "FEDEX_BOX",
    "pickupType": "USE_SCHEDULED_PICKUP",
    "blockInsightVisibility": false,
    "shippingChargesPayment": {
      "paymentType": "SENDER"
    },
    "labelSpecification": {
      "imageType": "PDF",
      "labelStockType": "PAPER_85X11_TOP_HALF_LABEL"
    },
    "requestedPackageLineItems": [
      {
        "weight": {
          "value": 4,
          "units": "LB"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "accountNumber": {
    "value": "740561073"
  }
}
```

I have the following for the header

```
Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    xmlHttp.Open "POST", url, False
    xmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken
    xmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    xmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
```

I am getting a proper accessToken, so I'm wondering if its my format but I keep comparing it to the example and see no problem

Any help is appreciated. I can provide more code if needed.

Here is the url I am posting to: "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/ship/v1/shipments"

and here is the exact response I receive:

`{"transactionId": "20479caf-d3d9-4a26-819c-d43f7e91c799","errors":[{"code":"BAD.REQUEST.ERROR","message":"The given JWT is invalid. Please modify your request and try again."}]}`

Now I suspect that my authorization is actually to blame. in every example on FedEx's site they receive a token with the scope of "cxs". My tokens have a scope of "oob". I have also noticed I receive a token no matter what credentials I put in.

Here are the examples I am referencing: https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/authorization/v1/docs.html

Here is the token I receive:

```
    {
      "access_token":"826deebc-0788-4bda-995c-e1cb5b588a51",
      "token_type":"Bearer",
      "expires_in":3600,
      "scope":"oob",
      

"resource": ["https://apis.fedex.com/*"]
}
```

Comment: Would help to include URL you're posting to, the exact response you get, plus the response headers (redacted as necessary)

Comment: Assuming your access token is valid that all looks OK to me...

Comment: Looking at the [API documentation](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/ship/v1/docs.html), the values for phoneNumber and postalCode should be wrapped in double quotes because they are strings. That doesn't really match up to the error you're seeing though. Also, ensure that the access token is less than an hour old because the tokens expire after 3600 seconds

Comment: Not sure if this will help anyone else, but in my case the problem was that the access_token was overflowing the **1KB** buffer I had assumed it would fit within.  FedEx and UPS generate absurdly long tokens!  (PayPal's are more sane.)